# Code works on localhost server but does nothing on live server

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm currently editing a pre-made website and have been asked to edit it so that when they click a button to delete a meeting task, it causes a confirmation box to appear instead of just deleting it.

The problem is, is that I got it to work on the test server and copied the code over but for some reason the code refuses to work on the live server, it just deletes the task instead.

The file is the view for the meetings section of the site and is mostly HTML with bits of PHP, not sure if that helps.

The servers seem to be the exact same as well.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php if ($this->session->userdata('manager_admin_user') == 'Y') { ?>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="/index.php/meetings/delete_meetingtask/<?= 
$meeting_task['meetingtask_id']?>"onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you 
want to delete this task?')">
        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>  
    </a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: well you should put spaces between your attributes `>"onclick`

Comment: It is possible that remote server PHP has [short_open_tag](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.short-open-tag) directive off. Try simple `echo` instead of `<?=` notation.

Comment: @ruuter it shouldn't be that, most the php is written which short tags so it definitely has them turned on since this is the only thing thats not working. all it's doing is ignoring the onclick section and deleting the task.

Comment: can you confirm the file is actually loaded? Try to narrow the possibilities of the problem. Can you execute any other js code from that same file? `alert("It's working!")` for example.

Comment: @ruuter I can confirm the file is loaded, as I've been editing the file I've been uploading it to the live server and seeing the view change. I don't however think the js is working for whatever reason, I tried to put an alert in the code that would appear when the page is loaded however nothing appeared.

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood the issue is in how the server rendered the markup. The easiest way to check and make sure your outputs are the same on the deployed version and you local is to compare the page source (you can usually right-click and choose "View page source").

If there isn't a difference there then we would need more information.